# Where to add Hooks and Filters code in WordPress for a Block Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am setting up a simple WordPress site and for future maintainability I have wanted to avoid any alteration of standard themes, especially as this is a favour for a charity without any real IT skills. Also, my requirements are simple enough that I can produce the site in the Block Editor, say with the Fork theme.

As I understand it, with the Site Editor approach, child themes are no longer required as all the tweaking of templates can be done in the Site Editor which are stored as posts in the DB. That all is good.

However, I want to use The Events Calendar and there are a couple of places where a hook or filter would just sort out a couple of issues. The code is easy enough, but where to put it?

As I do not have a child theme, I do not want to use functions.php as this can get overwritten by theme updates. Is there a right place to put hook and filter code for a Block Theme without using a child theme? I've seen a couple of comments about using `.htaccess`, but wasn't very clear on whether that was a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As your objective is adding "functionality" with hooks/filters and not "styling", a plugin best suits this scenario compared to a child theme.

I would suggest creating a plugin that first checks if The Events Calendar plugin is active before adding your hooks/filters. This way, the php code is entirely separate from the theme and the hooks/filters only run if the required plugin is activated.